# bash command quoted by single quote

Tags: bash, awk, grep, kill

I need to find process by string matching, and the kill it, need to do it in one line in another script file:
here's what I tried:

```
'kill $(ps -ef|grep xxx|grep -v grep | awk '{print $2 }' )'
```

```
"kill $(ps -ef|grep xxx|grep -v grep | awk '{print $2 }' )"
```

first one didn't work because of the nested single quote, second one didn't work because $2 is taken by the parent script to be argument 2 to parent script.
how do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to accomplish that task is:

```
pkill xxx
```

(which you'll find in the debian/ubuntu world in package `procps`, if you don't have it installed.) You might need to use `pkill -f xxx`, depending on whether xxx is part of the process name or an argument, which is often the case with script execution.

However, to answer the more general question about shell-quoting, if you need to pass the string

```
kill $(ps aux | grep xxx | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

as an argument, you need to use backslash escapes:

```
bash -c "kill \$(ps aux | grep xxx | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}')"
```

Or, you can paste together several quoted strings:

```
bash -c 'kill $(ps aux | grep xxx | grep -v grep | awk '"'"'{print $2}'"'"')'
```

Personally, I find the first one more readable but YMMV.

You can only backslash escape a few characters inside a double-quoted string: `$`, `"`, `\`, newline and backtick; and inside a single-quoted string backslash is just backslash. However, that's enough to let you type just about anything.